# Auto Loan Calculator Formulas

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I made simple Auto Loan Calculator that looks like below

But now my problem is what are the formulas should I use?

[image]

Comment: Post the code, not the image

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Please [do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=car+loan+algorithm)

Comment: EMI Amount = [P x R x (1+R)^N]/[(1+R)^N-1]  where P’ stands for the Principal Amount, ‘R’ stands for the Rate of Interest set by the bank and N is the number of years given for the repayment of the loan. As you must pay the EMIs each month, the duration is calculated in the number of months.

Comment: Do you know what the formulae are and are struggling to write them in code. Or are you at a complete loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula

## Loan Payment (P) = Amount (A) / Discount Factor (D)

**Stick with us here, as this one gets a little hairy. To solve the equation, you’ll need to find the numbers for these values:**

A = Total loan amount

D = {[(1 + r)n] - 1} / [r(1 + r)n]

Periodic Interest Rate (r) = Annual rate (converted to decimal figure) divided by number of payment periods

Number of Periodic Payments (n) = Payments per year multiplied by the number of years

**Here’s an example: let’s say you get an auto loan for $10,000 at 3% for 7 years. It would shake out like this:**

n = 84 (12 monthly payments per year x 7 years)

r = 0.0025 (a 3% rate converted to 0.03, divided by 12 payments per year)

D = 75.6813 {[(1+0.0025)84] - 1} / [0.0025(1+0.0025)84]

P = $132.13 (10,000 / 75.6813

In this case, your monthly loan payment for your car would be $132.13.

## But this really depends on the type of loan that you want to calculate

Comment: yes that what i looking for.But how can i find Total Interest

Answer (score 0):

Before you start crunching the numbers, it’s important to first know what kind of loan you’re getting — an interest-only loan or amortizing loan.

With an interest-only loan, you would only pay interest for the first few years, and nothing on the principal. Repayments on amortizing loans, on the other hand, include both the interest and principal over a set length of time (i.e. the term).

The next step is plugging numbers into this loan payment formula based on your loan type.

For amortizing loans, the monthly payment formula is:

**Loan Payment (P) = Amount (A) / Discount Factor (D)**

Stick with us here, as this one gets a little hairy. To solve the equation, you’ll need to find the numbers for these values:

```
*A = Total loan amount
D = {[(1 + r)n] - 1} / [r(1 + r)n]
Periodic Interest Rate (r) = Annual rate (converted to decimal figure) divided by number of payment periods
Number of Periodic Payments (n) = Payments per year multiplied by number of years*
```

Here’s an example: let’s say you get an auto loan for $10,000 at 3% for 7 years. It would shake out as this:

```
*n = 84 (12 monthly payments per year x 7 years)
r = 0.0025 (a 3% rate converted to 0.03, divided by 12 payments per year)
D = 75.6813 {[(1+0.0025)84] - 1} / [0.0025(1+0.0025)84]
P = $132.13 (10,000 / 75.6813)*
```

In this case, your monthly loan payment for your car would be $132.13.

If you have an interest-only loan, calculating loan payments is a lot easier. The formula is:

**Loan Payment = Loan Balance x (annual interest rate/12)**

In this case, your monthly interest-only payment for the loan above would be $25.

First Study What you want to do or what client wants & right now how are they calculating

Comment: how can i add down payment

Comment: A down payment is the initial cash that goes towards any purchase paid for with a loan. For mortgages and car loans, consumers usually pay 3% to 20% of the asset's cost with their own cash and borrow the rest of the purchase amount. The following is a typical example of a car purchase financed with a down payment and installment loan, a type of loan paid off over time.
Car Purchase Price $25,000
Down Payment $7,500 (30%)
Loan Amount $17,500
Loan Repayment Term 60 months
Interest Rate (APR) 5%
Monthly Payment $330

I hope you got the concept how you can add the down payment